# Bootstrap tooltip hover issue when apply on button which is part of button group

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I applied a tooltip to a button which is a part of button group like:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="tooltip test 123">
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
         <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".btn").tooltip();
});
```

and jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lo9dkf2/

When you hover that button, you'll see that tooltip is not positioned correctly and you cannot click on that button to trigger a dropdown.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like following way:

```js
$(function(){
 $(".btn-group").tooltip();
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 330px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group pull-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="tooltip test 123">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
         <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lo9dkf2/2/)**

Comment: @SnakeEyes. There is another hack is https://jsfiddle.net/4Lo9dkf2/3/. Wrap inside another div and make changes in css. https://jsfiddle.net/4Lo9dkf2/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try it;

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right" style="position: absolute;">
    <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="dropdown" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="tooltip test 123">
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">
         <li>Test</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```